# Space and line-end indicators stay after switching off whitespace-mode

Tags: whitespace, whitespace-mode

When I switch on whitespace-mode I get all the indicators and color for showing superfluous whitespace. So far so good.

But when I switch *off* whitespace-mode the space indicator `.` and the line-end indicator `$` stay.

How can I switch them off as well, so that the buffer looks normal again?

Comment: Can you provide a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @phils I cannot reproduce it with a vanilla Emacs. Must be an issue with my set-up. (`helm` might interfere???)

Comment: Certainly test anything you suspect is the issue, but if you're at a loss then recursive bisection of your config is an efficient way to try to track down the culprit. https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter might help to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the set up with a multitude of additional packages is responsible for this problem. (Vanilla Emacs does not have this issue.) But it is hard to determine what *exactly* causes the problem.

However *if* the issue occurs, a manual ad hoc fix is possible: Just erase the local display table. I have defined a command for this:

```
(defun my-erase-local-display-table ()
  (interactive)
  (if buffer-display-table
      (setq leo-buffer-display-table-backup buffer-display-table))
  (setq buffer-display-table nil))
```

When things get pear-shaped in a buffer, just call this comamnd and everything should be back to normal.